# Sign soap message with apache cxf

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, security, cxf

I am writing some web service endpoint in spring boot and cxf that returns soap messages.
One of the requirement is to sign messages coming out from my servic using key from keytstore/trustore.
The result of signing message is to add Security element with signatures and SignatureValue as specified by ws security standard. to the soap header.
I am very fresh to the security related topics - can anyone point to the documentation how to do that in cxf or spring security please?

Best regards

I have tried some wss4j classes but without success.